# Resolving dependencies of .dll

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to load dependant assemblies in .NET Core 2.2 however I hit the wall.

Let's consider we have console app "A". This console app receives a path to folder that contains plugin (B ->.dll project) it should load. Plugin "B" have it's own dependencies that are mostly nuget packages. Situation in short looks like

A (loads) -> B (uses) -> (Entity Framework, Newtonsoft Json, etc...)

And now, here is my problem: I can load B through AssemblyLoadContext however there is no nuget packages in the folder of released "B".

I assume that (as I'm publishing my modules as "portable" version) dependencies loader should resolve (reach to nuget server and download the dependencies?) somehow nuget packages but for reason it doesn't.

How can I properly resolve those dependencies?

Comment: That's not how NuGet works. Your dependencies should be present at compile time and have to be deployed with your application.

Comment: Compiling module "B" doesn't give me the dependant assemblies, where are they then?

Comment: Do you have [package restore enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I do. It doesn't include those libraries to \bin\release folder.